# Can't Find Ubuntu AMI Update SNS Subscription

Tags: updates, aws

In light of the meltdown/spectre exploits we want to be on top of keeping all of our company's Ubuntu images in AWS (AMI) up to date. We already have a system to rebuild all of our Ubuntu images that we internally call the "Bakery".

In part of driving this effort we want to automate when everything is re-built and triggered on new releases in the AWS AMI Marketplace. To accomplish this we are subscribing to SNS topics. Finding the windows SNS subscription was fairly easy with some googling, however finding the Ubuntu AMI update subscription ARN has been impossible for about 4 hours of just googling.

Does anyone here have the ARN for the SNS Subscription of Ubuntu AMI updates? I know it HAS to start with something like this: `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:099720109477:*` (where `099720109477` is the AWS account ID of the ubuntu images owner) but I don't know the name of the topic to replace the `*`

I'd even be open to creating this feature for Ubuntu releases, but I don't want to re-create the wheel that I'm really positive already exists.

Any help or better ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!